# background image with scrollbars

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

i got a little newbie question:
I need to put an image to be a background image of a site. and it needs to show the whole image. The user need to have the option to scroll down.
This is what i wrote and it does show the scroll bars but it doesn't scroll.
The image is very big.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("OPL2013.gif"); /* Change Image URL */
            background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Keep it */
            background-position: 50% 0; /* position to center */
            background-attachment: fixed; /* For Scrolling bars */
            height: 100%;
            min-height:100%;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body dir="rtl" align="center">
</body>
</html>
```

**The image is 970X1200 Pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting background image, you are simply applying an image to the visible area as determined by the element it is applied to.

As such, you will likely want to add the image as an `img` element into your `body`, or explicitly set the dimensions of the `body` itself to those of the image.

The reason scrollbars arent being shown is that they are dictated by the overflow of an element, which is determined by its content. The background property does not represent content propagated to the element, as such- it cannot influence overflow and thereby cause scrollbars to appear. This is why you will need to either change the dimensions of the element to create overflow on its parent, or apply the image as the `src` of an `img` to do the same.